# How to design a serverside heartbeat with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would post this on https://stackoverflow.com/, but figured **I am not looking for code**, just an idea how to accomplish this.

I have a gameserver that interacts with `nodejs` and uses the `websocket` module. It works great, there is one problem:

When a user is joining a game and the map gets loaded, a user could easily press F12, go into Chrome dev tools and remove the `overflow:hidden` css attribute, thus.. revealing the rest of the map. (A Web-based map hack!). My map dimensions are 3000x3000 + in size.

I need some type of way to to send something to nodejs every xx seconds and then nodejs needs to send back a token with that request as well to keep that css attribute at `overflow:hidden` and if the data being sent is manipulated in anyway, I can then shut down that player's connection.

Doing this method, I would use the `setInterval` with Javascript to create the heartbeat. Am I going about this the right way?

Edit: And yes, this will require more bandwidth, but well worth it imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be better off using that extra bandwidth to spoon feed the map to the users as they discover it.

As you've noticed, **anything client side can be easily hacked.**  You might think of a fancy way to encrypt the data, but you'd still have to send the decrypt keys to the browser.

For that matter, you don't really know if you're talking to a browser at all - you're just sending data over a TCP port to a computer that kind of maybe sort of looks like it might be a common web browser.

Comment: Sweet. I will give this a try intead. So, let's say when a playing is moving around the map, have a trigger at an XY position or different points around the map (my game is 2d isometrics) to load in the tiles/monsters dynamically?

Comment: That sounds right to me.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I had a light-bulb moment after reading your answer, ha.